# Connecting to spotify ap via proxy, Host not found, Error 4

Tags: android, android-ndk, spotify

I try to connect to spotify from android phone with their spotify android lib.
Using phone's wifi connection.

Logs:

```
13:56:20.389 I [ap:1750] Connecting to AP ap.spotify.com:443 via proxy http://�:80
13:56:41.753 E [ap:1694] AP Socket Error: Host not found (20001)
13:56:41.753 E [ap:3915] Connection error:  4
```

Any idea, thanks.

References:

https://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/no_internet_connection_detected_error_code_4
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/decode-spotify-error-messages-and-codes.html
["Logged in" callback never called by libspotify on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880182/logged-in-callback-never-called-by-libspotify-on-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that you're not clearing out your variables before making the connection to the service. You need to `memset` all structures before initializing them; if there are uninitialized fields, they will probably be filled with "garbage" (ie, whatever was in the memory contents when the object was allocated) and cause libspotify to mistakenly believe that you have set a proxy to the service.

Comment: Thanks. no proxy, and connected!

Comment: Cool, glad to hear that you got it working! Don't forget to mark the answer as correct to help future people arriving from Google and other such sources.